# Does Swimm have issues with alternative git installs, such as using Homebrew on macOS?

Tags: git, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, swimm

Getting an error in the WebStorm Swimm plugin that shows

[image]

No other applications are yelling at me about an invalid git, and it is most definitely on my PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh! Background version update on XCode invalidated the license agreements. All I had to do was open XCode and accept the terms ...

Although this prompts another question ... is swim hard-coded to rely on the system `git` installed by apple? If so why?